# Why does this script work when it is run from an IDE but not when run by using os.system()?

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have two python files on a Raspberry Pi4.  One logs temperature data from 16 RTD sensors to a .csv file.  The other clears the .csv by writing the sensor labels to the first row.  The clearData.py script works fine when I run it from my IDE (mu).  When I call it from the other script it runs and prints "CLEARED" to the console but the file is not cleared.
I call clearData.py using `os.system("python3 clearData.py")` Any suggestions?

clearData.py:

```
file = open("data.csv", 'w')
file.write("RTD 0-1 °C,RTD 0-2 °C,RTD 0-3 °C,RTD 0-4 °C,RTD 0-5 °C,RTD 0-6 °C,RTD 0-7 °C,RTD 0-8 °C,RTD 1-1 °C,RTD 1-2 °C,RTD 1-3 °C,RTD 1-4 °C,RTD 1-5 °C,RTD 1-6 °C,RTD 1-7 °C,RTD 1-8 °C")
file.close()
print("DATA CLEARED")
```

Comment: It looks like [relative] path issue. Check what is CWD in both cases (I guess it's different) and you create a second file on different location. Use `print(os.getcwd())`. Or simply use absolute path to file.

Comment: Thank you, using the absolute path worked.